# Where is the log file for fsck on Kali v2.0?

Tags: logs, kali-linux, fsck

I am testing [Kali Linux](https://www.kali.org/downloads/) v2.0, and I am not able to locate the log file for `fsck` scans.

On **Ubuntu v14** I found it here:

```
luis@Terminus:~$ locate mountall.log
/var/log/upstart/mountall.log.1.gz
/var/log/upstart/mountall.log.2.gz
/var/log/upstart/mountall.log.3.gz
/var/log/upstart/mountall.log.4.gz
/var/log/upstart/mountall.log.5.gz
/var/log/upstart/mountall.log.6.gz
/var/log/upstart/mountall.log.7.gz
```

But it doesn't seem to exist on Kali:

```
luis@Midnighter:~$ sudo locate mountall
/etc/init.d/mountall-bootclean.sh
/etc/init.d/mountall.sh
/etc/rcS.d/S11mountall.sh
/etc/rcS.d/S12mountall-bootclean.sh
/lib/systemd/system/mountall-bootclean.service
/lib/systemd/system/mountall.service
```

Results with `find` command:

```
luis@Midnighter:~$ sudo find / -name "mountall.log*"
luis@Midnighter:~$ sudo find / -name "mountall*"
/lib/systemd/system/mountall.service
/lib/systemd/system/mountall-bootclean.service
/run/systemd/generator/mountall-bootclean.service.d
/run/systemd/generator/mountall.service.d
/etc/init.d/mountall.sh
/etc/init.d/mountall-bootclean.sh
```

Where is it located?

Answer (score 1):

> the log file for fsck scans

Technically, the "log file" for `fsck` is [standard out/standard error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).  This can be redirected and captured, but it is not necessarily so.

As a complication, keep in mind that when that `fsck` is run, the filesystem is not writable, so it is not just a matter of `&> /var/log/mountall.log`.  Its output must be captured then logged afterward at some point.

Using `/forcefsck` or an equivalent kernel param (e.g., `fsck.mode=force`), the actual fsck is run by [init](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) (in the case of the kernel param it is passed through, so this may not be universal in form).  How init handles this depends on the init; evidently upstart, on Ubuntu, saves the output and logs it (perhaps, keep reading).  Systemd seems to report a few details via syslog (if enabled, and presumably its own journal).

I'm not sure that systems based on pre-8 (systemd) Debian log this at all, or even how it was handled. The SysV script `/etc/init.d/mountall.sh` does not refer to fsck, but of course `mount` will invoke it automatically if the filesystem has not been checked recently enough (this may be what you are actually used to seeing in upstart's mountall.log, which is why I wrote "perhaps" earlier).

So, handling of "forcefsck" is probably built right into the SysV init executable.  It does produce output on the console but I have never noticed that recorded anywhere on Debian.

If you want to check the last time a filesystem was fsck'd, use:

```
dumpe2fs -h /dev/[node]| grep "Mount count"
```

Where [node] is a real partition. This is the number of times the fs has been mounted since the last check (minimally 1, if it is currently mounted).

Comment: How sad not being able to know what the `fsck` did. Is there at least any way to know that my `#touch /forcefsck` was executed as requested during boot?

Comment: It is a bit obtuse.  Have a look in `/var/log/boot.log` -- I don't have a SysV system to check except for logs from <= Debian 7, and I don't save copies of that one.  WRT "Did it run?", look at `dumpe2fs`; it will say how many mounts since the last check.

Comment: `dumpe2fs /dev/mmcblk0p2 | grep "mount" -i` shows some `Mount count` numeric value that corresponds to the number of reboots after my last `fsck`. If this is some generic method, it could be worth for you to write it in your answer. Thanks you.

Comment: Good point -- added that.